# Using django-mongodb, how to sort descending a capped collection?

Tags: django, sorting, mongodb, django-nonrel

Have this model, a class representing a capped collection at mongodb:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   objects = MongoDBManager()
   create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   obj = BlobField()
   class MongoMeta:
      capped = True
      collection_size = 1000*1024*1024
```

What can I use to get the documents in the reverse order they are inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporal solution at pymongo level, **not** django-mongodb level:

```
from django.db import connections
import pymongo

conn = connections['default']
events_col = conn.get_collection('base_event')
events = events_col.find().sort('create_at', pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python person but I can tell you that capped collections [Natural Order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order) is the order of insertion.  Therefore you can just do the python equivalent of this to get the reverse order:

```
db.cappedCollection.find().sort({$natural:-1})
```

A bit of googling tells me this translates to something like the following in python:

```
 mongodb.cappedcol.find().sort('$natural',-1)
```

Or:

```
 mongodb.cappedcol.find().sort('$natural', pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Comment: This works, but it is javascript at mongodb CLI. I'm need a solution at django-mongodb level. Thanks anyway Adam.

Answer (score 0):

- We didn't have any tests for capped collection support so it was broken before now. I just fixed it, please use the `master` branch of our [Git repository](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine) to get the working version.
- Reverse-natural ordering isn't implemented yet. I opened a bug https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/106, patches welcome!